# Problema com upload de imagens: Warning: move_uploaded_file():

Tags: php, jquery, html

Meu código está aparecendo um erro que nunca apareceu antes, quando testo no localhost (utilizo o xampp) as imagens são inseridas com sucesso no site, mas quando faço com o site hospedado ele aparece o seguinte erro:

Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/1193699972.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u755489537/public_html/upload/upload.php on line 73

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpXzwvDc' to 'uploads/1193699972.jpg' in /home/u755489537/public_html/upload/upload.php on line 73

Sempre funcionou, porém agora começou a dar erro, e eu não mexi em nenhuma linha do meu código, simplismente começou a dar erro.
Meu servidor de hospedagem é o Hostinger, será que o problema é do servidor?

Meu código é:

```html
<?php
 require_once("../connect.php"); 
?>

<?php
 if(!isset($_SESSION["email_profissional"]) || !isset($_SESSION["senha_profissional"])){
  header("Location:logout.php");
  exit;
 }else{
  
 }
 if(is_numeric($_GET['sessao'])){  
 }else{
  header("location:logout.php");
 }
  
 if($_GET['sessao'] == null){
  header("location:logout.php");
 }

 if($_GET['sessao'] != preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "",$_SESSION['protecao'])){
  header("location:logout.php");
 }else{
  $sessao = $_GET['sessao'];
 }
?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
  
  //INFORMAÇÃO DAS IMAGEM
  $file = $_FILES['img'];
  $profissional = $_POST['profissional'];
  $numFile = count(array_filter($file['name']));
  
  //PASTA
  $folder = '../upload/uploads';
  
  //REQUISITOS QUE A IMAGEM DEVE OBEDESCER
  $permite = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png');
  $maxSize = 1024 * 1024 * 20;

  //MENSAGENS
  $msg = array();
  $errorMsg = array(
   1 => 'O arquivo enviado excede o limite definido na diretiva upload_max_filesize do php.ini.',
   2 => 'O arquivo excede o limite definido em MAX_FILE_SIZE no formulário HTML.',
   3 => 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente.',
   4 => 'Nenhum arquivo foi enviado.',
   );
  
  if($numFile <= 0)
   echo 'Selecione uma imagem';
  else{
   for($i = 0; $i < $numFile; $i++){
    $name = $file['name'][$i];
    $type = $file['type'][$i];
    $size = $file['size'][$i];
    $error = $file ['error'][$i];
    $tmp = $file['tmp_name'][$i];
    
    
    $extensao = @end(explode('.', $name));
    $novoNome = rand().".$extensao";
    
    if($error != 0)
     echo "<b style='font-family:arial; color:red;'>$name :</b><p style='font-family:arial; color:red;'> ".$errorMsg[$error]."</p>";
    else if(!in_array($type, $permite))
     echo "<b style='font-family:arial; color:red;'>$name :</b> <p style='font-family:arial; color:red;'> Erro! Imagem não suportada. Use apenas imagens JPG ou PNG</p>";
    else if($size > $maxSize)
     echo "<b style='font-family:arial; color:red;'>$name :</b> <p  style='font-family:arial; color:red;'>Erro! Imagem ultrapassa o limite de 20MB.</p>";
    else{
     if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder.'/'.$novoNome)){
      $sql = "INSERT INTO arquivo (id_arquivo, nome_arquivo, profissional) VALUES (null, '$novoNome', '$profissional')";
      //conexão com o banco de dados
      $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Configuração de Banco de Dados Errada!");
      //Selecionando o banco de dados...
      mysqli_select_db($con, $db) or die ("Banco de Dados Inexistente!");
      //Inserindo os dados
      mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die ("<font style=Arial color=red><h1>Houve um erro na gravação dos dados</h1></font>");
      echo "<font style=Arial color=green><b>".$name.": Cadastro efetuado com sucesso! O arquivo foi renomeado para ".$novoNome."</b></font><br>";      
     }else{
      echo "<font style=Arial color=red font-weight=bold><b>".$name.": Falha!</b></font><br>";
     }    
    }
   } 
  } 
 }
```

Comment: A pasta `uploads` existe?

Comment: Desculpe, foi um erro besta meu, eu apaguei a pasta uploads e não tinha percebido. Obrigado!